# Stored Procedure testing

Tags: sql, sql-server, testing, stored-procedures, business-rules

I am in a healthcare project, where majority of the business written in stored procedures. How can i test the stored procedures to check the data is flowing per business or not? Is it through any testing tool i should use to achieve this? If Yes, then please tell me the tools name. I need to test the data field by field. Please confirm.

Comment: Please explain your question. What do you mean by testing. Mocking, Unit Testing. What type of testing you want. If stored procedure have some insert/update/delete queries then it will change the data.

Comment: It's a unit testing, we are filtering source data using stored procedure, we would like to know the stored procedure is passing the correct data to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two major options:

1: Write your own unit testing scenarios. You can follow this link for better guidance: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851212(v=vs.103).aspx

2: You can use some third party tools to test your stored procedures. Some of these tools are:

- [T.S.T](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=tst)

> TST simplifies the task of writing and running test automation for
>   T-SQL code. Written in T-SQL it provides an API similar to those
>   provided by other Unit Testing frameworks. Can produce test reports in
>   XML format. It provides automatic rollback, dataset comparison
>   support, etc.

- [Red-Gate SQL Test](https://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-test/)

> If you want to do SQL Server unit testing in T-SQL, and run it as part
>   of your automated builds, SQL Test is the place to start. It's simple
>   to set up, you don’t need extra tools, and you don't need to learn new
>   technologies. SQL Test also comes with pre-written SQL Cop tests, to
>   help you enforce best practices for database development and run
>   static analysis tests.

- [tSQLt](https://tsqlt.org/)

> Importantly, because tSQLt allows you to implement unit tests in
>   T-SQL, you don’t have to switch between various tools to create the
>   code and unit tests.

You can also find many other tools, similar to these.